# Unrecognized win32 error code building application in VScode with Pyrseas and Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I get  an unrecognized win32 error code when building an application in VSCode under windows. The application is using pyrseas to interact with postgres. I have python, pyrseas, IIS installed. I have a pgconfig file that my enviroment variables are pointing to, containing my password and port details.  How do I resolve this error ? Below is the relevant output from the build

```
6>DBUpdate
6>Drive is C:
6>Folder is C:\Projects\MySkills\Source\Database\UpgradeScripts\
6>Creating YAML file...
6>EXEC : unrecognized win32 error code: 123Traceback (most recent call last):
6>  File "dbtoyaml.py", line 57, in <module>
6>    main()
6>  File "dbtoyaml.py", line 49, in main
6>    dbmap = db.to_map()
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-    py3.8.egg\pyrseas\database.py", line 443, in to_map
6>    self.from_catalog(True)
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\database.py", line 349, in from_catalog
6>    self.db = self.Dicts(self.dbconn, single_db)
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\database.py", line 92, in __init__
6>    self.schemas = SchemaDict(dbconn)
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\dbobject\__init__.py", line 633, in __init__
6>    self._from_catalog()
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\dbobject\__init__.py", line 640, in _from_catalog
6>    for obj in self.fetch():
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\dbobject\__init__.py", line 682, in fetch
6>    self.query = self.cls.query(self.dbconn.version)
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\database.py", line 77, in version
6>    self.connect()
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyrseas-0.9.1-py3.8.egg\pyrseas\database.py", line 63, in connect
6>    super(CatDbConnection, self).connect()
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pgdbconn-0.8.0-py3.8.egg\pgdbconn\dbconn.py", line 50, in connect
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pgdbconn-0.8.0-py3.8.egg\pgdbconn\dbconn.py", line 43, in connect
6>  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.9.6-py3.8-win32.egg\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
6>    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
6>psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
6>
6>        1 file(s) moved.
6>Extracting plain SQL file...
6>Extracting plain data sql file
```

Expected build to complete. Have checked python install. Have tried reinstalling pyrseas. Have reinstalled postgres and checked the postgres config files and they look sensible.

Comment: Could you add the code snippet that establishes the connection to the db in your question? It's difficult to tell what exactly is happening here